# How to auto generate date time and image columns in wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a custom object which contains `datetime` , `string` and `image uri` properties.

As of now I am generating columns manually using template columns.

Since I have to use only **one** datagrid and datasource is dynamic for **four** different scenarios within the application, I need to auto generate columns just by setting `ItemsSource` property of the datagrid.

So, my question is if I set the `ItemsSource` according to scenario, will it generate all columns accordingly. (datetime , string and image)

Also, these columns need to be **sortable**.

Comment: Is it the built-in `DataGrid`? If so, you just have to remove the templated columns and set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `true`...

Comment: Yes, it is built-in datagrid, Will it generate sortable datetime and image columns accordingly.

Comment: As far as I remember, the columns in DataGrid are sortable by default. It's different with filtering though... :) The column header on the generated column will have the same name as the source property name.

Comment: that means, string columns will have default string sorting and datetime columns will have datetime sorting.

Comment: As far as I know - yes.

Comment: I did a sample, it is not working for images, just display the uris

Comment: I would personally generate 4 different data templates for the four scenarios, and then select from them based on need.